# Yellowbox error when upgrading to React Native 0.63.2

Tags: ios, react-native

I've followed all of the instructions in the migration guide when upgrading from 62.2 to 63.2. I have no console.warns or YellowBox imports / calls in my project.

[image]

```sh
error: Error: Unable to resolve module `./Libraries/YellowBox/YellowBox` from `node_modules/react-native/index.js`: 

None of these files exist:
  * node_modules/react-native/Libraries/YellowBox/YellowBox(.native|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * node_modules/react-native/Libraries/YellowBox/YellowBox/index(.native|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/qq/example/example-app/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:163:15)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (/Users/qq/example/example-app/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/qq/example/example-app/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:287:16)
    at Object.resolve (/Users/qq/example/example-app/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:267:42)
    at /Users/qq/example/example-app/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:434:31
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (/Users/qq/example/example-app/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:431:18)
    at /Users/qq/example/example-app/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:275:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/Users/qq/example/example-app/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:87:24)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try doing this...

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```

Then this

```
npx react-native run-android
```

Check more here
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1924

Answer (score 0):

**Yellowbox is now deprecated!**

I have used LogBox

```
import {LogBox} from 'react-native';
LogBox.ignoreAllLogs();
```